# function for toggling a symbol inside a FullForm

Tags: formatting

Hello I would like to build a function for the hermitic conjugation of f[i]. When applied to f[i], it should result in `f\[Dagger][i]`, and when applied to `f\[Dagger][i]`, it should result in f[i], where i is some integer. How could I do that please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean conjugate transpose, Hermitian conjugate, Hermitian adjoint? What would the function be operating on? Have you tried anything at all? Give us some more detail.

Comment: To answer MarcoB: All I need is the symbolic manipulation mentioned in my post. f[i] is an abstract object (second quantization operator). All I need is to toggle the `\[Dagger]` part of the FullForm. In case you wonder why, I am trying to use the package DiracQ for quantum calculations, but it lacks this simple formal operation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the package you using, but if by "toggling the `\[Dagger]`" you mean converting the expression `f[i]` to `(f^\[Dagger])[i]`, which is equivalent to `SuperDagger[f][i]`, then you need to define something like this:

```
Dagger[f_] := Operate[SuperDagger, f]
SuperDagger[SuperDagger[x_]] := x
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out, converting the argument to String and using StringReplace and RegularExpression inside a Module to toggle the dagger symbol.

Example code:

```
    ToManipString[a_] := ToString[FullForm[ToBoxes[a]]];
BackToExpres[a_] := 
  ReleaseHold[MakeExpression[ToExpression[a], StandardForm]];

Dag[a_] := 
 Module[{}, 
  newstr = BackToExpres[
    StringReplace[
     ToManipString[a], {"\"\\[Sigma]\"" -> "\"\[Sigma]\[Dagger]\"", 
      "\"b\"" -> "\"b\\[Dagger]\""}]];
  If[newstr == 
    a, {newstr = 
     BackToExpres[
      StringReplace[
       ToManipString[a], {"\"\\[Sigma]\\[Dagger]\"" -> "\"\[Sigma]\"",
         "\"b\\[Dagger]\"" -> "\"b\""}]]}, newstr];
```

This version works for "b" and "sigma" operators multiplied by symbolic stuff, like sqrt(2).

Comment: You might consider including code in your answer to be useful to others as well.

Comment: I suggest that you post some background on what you want to achieve... I am pretty confident that there is a better way to do what you want